# .NET lib for interpreting user agent strings

Tags: c#, .net, user-agent

Are there and .NET libs out there that will interpret stored user agent strings and give you a nice strongly typed object with the contained information?

Comment: Check this link - Hope this helps you - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/04/27/412813.aspx

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNETFrameworkAndTheBrowsersUserAgentString.aspx

Comment: Check this link: [http://user-agent-string.info/download/UASparser-for-dotNET](http://user-agent-string.info/download/UASparser-for-dotNET)

Comment: I am working on it, since most libraries are discontinued or works bad: https://github.com/OrbintSoft/yauaa.netstandard

Answer (score 18):

```
        var browserCapabilities = new HttpBrowserCapabilities
        {
            Capabilities = new Hashtable { { string.Empty, userAgent } }
        };

        var capabilitiesFactory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();

        capabilitiesFactory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(new NameValueCollection(), browserCapabilities);

        return browserCapabilities;
```

Comment: Great for Browser but wimpy on O/S (Platform returns "WinNT").

Answer (score 12):

You could try this [ua-parser](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser) it seems to be updated fairly often!

Edit: It seems ua-parser is more or less dead now, [DeviceDetector.NET](https://github.com/totpero/DeviceDetector.NET) seems to be in active development.

Comment: Sadly that was in 2013, now it's discontinued

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti i added an alternative that seems like its in active decelopment (i have not tried it yet)

Comment: yeah, sure better than a discontinued, but I tried many libraries and there isn't one that works well for .NET so I decided to create one by myself: github.com/OrbintSoft/yauaa.netstandard
It's not easy to parse an user agent, most libraries depends on a database of regex that needs to be continually updated: I working on a different approach adapting a java library with an ANTLR parser

Answer (score 5):

You can use the HttpRequest.Browser property if its for that you want the user agent string.
Try to program your websites against browser Capabilities instead of browser versions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities bc = Request.Browser;
Response.Write("<p>Browser Capabilities:</p>");
Response.Write("Type = " + bc.Type + "<br>");
Response.Write("Name = " + bc.Browser + "<br>");
Response.Write("Version = " + bc.Version + "<br>");
Response.Write("Major Version = " + bc.MajorVersion + "<br>");
Response.Write("Minor Version = " + bc.MinorVersion + "<br>");
Response.Write("Platform = " + bc.Platform + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Beta = " + bc.Beta + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Crawler = " + bc.Crawler + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is AOL = " + bc.AOL + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Win16 = " + bc.Win16 + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Win32 = " + bc.Win32 + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Frames = " + bc.Frames + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Tables = " + bc.Tables + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Cookies = " + bc.Cookies + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports VB Script = " + bc.VBScript + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports JavaScript = " + bc.JavaScript + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Java Applets = " + bc.JavaApplets + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports ActiveX Controls = " + bc.ActiveXControls + "<br>");
Response.Write("CDF = " + bc.CDF + "<br>");
```

Comment: I'm working from a log of user agent strings. Is there any way to use HttpBrowserCapabilities to parse a user agent string (long) after the http request?

Comment: Maybe you can create a httprequest and then set the headers from your agent string and it will work that way, havent tested it.